# Using Python's multiprocessing.shared_memory I still need to create an (initial) copy of the object I'm sharing. Or do I?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

I'm experimenting with Python's `multiprocessing.shared_memory` and `multiprocessing.managers.SharedMemoryManager`. I've created the following minimal code to get a grip of the process:

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import SharedMemoryManager

import numpy as np


def main():
    x = np.random.randn(10_000_000)
    n_jobs = 25
    n_workers = 4

    with SharedMemoryManager() as smm, Pool(n_workers) as pool:
        shm = smm.SharedMemory(x.nbytes)
        y = np.ndarray(x.shape, dtype=x.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
        y[:] = x[:]
        sample_means = pool.starmap(func, [(shm.name, x.shape, x.dtype)] * n_jobs)


def func(shm_name, shape, dtype):
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm_name, create=False)
    x = np.ndarray(shape, dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    sample_mean = np.random.choice(x, size=10_000, replace=False).mean()
    return sample_mean


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So using the `shared_memory` functionality we avoid making duplicates of the large numpy array `x`, which is good. However, it seems to me that the line `y[:] = x[:]` is actually creating a copy of `x` (in `y`). True, it happens only once (not for every process) but my question is - is it avoidable?
If `x` is a huge dataset I want to share between my workers I'd rather not make copies of it at all. Is it possible?

Comment: The code copies the contents of one array to the other, yes (`y[:] = x[:]`). Creating the shared array and then populating it via another means (eg. in a loop or non-materialized sequence) would avoid the temporary “duplicate” array / memory. Still have to take in account the size and potentially access considerations.

Comment: @user2864740, can you perhaps draft a small code snippet to demonstrate what you mean by "populating it via another means"? I can't think of any other means to populate a `shared_memory` object once I already have the dataset (or something similar) loaded to memory in my main script.